# MySQL select one, two or any

Tags: php, mysql

How can i pick between 2 ites or both of them?
I'm trying to use this script but its returning an error.

```
if ($company == "ANY") {
    $query_company = '*';
}
elseif ($company == "AMD") {
    $query_company = 'AMD';
}
elseif ($company == "Intel") {
    $query_company = 'Intel';
}

$card_data =  mysqli_query($con, 
    "SELECT * FROM builds 
    WHERE
        approved = 'yes'
        AND manufacturer = $query_company
        AND build_price BETWEEN $price_min
    AND $price_max
    ");
```

(I'm getting the $company from the url with GET)
Any way to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Use the `like` keyword

Comment: You are missing one `AND` in your `WHERE` clause

Comment: What is the error?  Instead of directly executing your SQL, echo it to the screen.  What does it say?

Comment: Don't use the asterisk, just remove the manufacturer from the query if none is specified.

Comment: @kingkero sounds more like he is french ;)

Comment: None of the above, but edited to "asterisk" now!

Comment: And if for some reason you have to pick one of them randomly, I'd do `array_rand(array('AMD', 'Intel'))`, as I hate the asterisk

Comment: @adeneo if i leave it empty it will try to find something with empty manufacturer

Comment: Then use something that selects one of them randomly, like in the comment I posted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM builds 
WHERE approved = 'yes' and
      (manufacturer = $query_company or $query_company = '*') and
      build_price BETWEEN $price_min AND $price_max;
```

I'm just posting this as an example for your logic (so avoiding issues such as SQL injection).  However, I would suggest that you make two different queries in the application:

```
SELECT *
FROM builds 
WHERE approved = 'yes' and
      manufacturer = $query_company and
      build_price BETWEEN $price_min AND $price_max;
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM builds 
WHERE approved = 'yes' and
      build_price BETWEEN $price_min AND $price_max;
```

The advantage of this approach is that these queries can take advantage of indexes.  The first `builds(manufacturer, approved, build_price)` and the second `builds(approved, build_price)`.  The single query with the `or` (or `like`) cannot be optimized as well.

EDIT:

Let me be clearer about the second option:

```
if ($company == "ANY") {
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM builds 
            WHERE approved = 'yes' and
                  build_price BETWEEN $price_min AND $price_max"
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM builds 
            WHERE approved = 'yes' and
                  manufacturer LIKE '$query_company' and
                  build_price BETWEEN $price_min AND $price_max"
}

$card_data =  mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

This is just an example.  You can preassign $sql to most of the query and then just add the additional clause in the `if` statement.  This approach has another advantage.  You can print out `$sql` after the variable substitution to see what it looks like.

That said, you should learn how to switch to parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the `LIKE` operator (Notice I replaced your `*` witha a `%`):

```
if ($company == "ANY") {
    $query_company = '*';
}
elseif ($company == "AMD") {
    $query_company = 'AMD';
}
elseif ($company == "Intel") {
    $query_company = 'Intel';
}

$card_data =  mysqli_query($con, 
"SELECT * FROM builds 
WHERE approved = 'yes' 
manufacturer LIKE '$query_company'
and build_price BETWEEN $price_min
AND $price_max");
```